# Does IBM APIConnect have IP white or black listing?

Tags: apiconnect

Does IBM APIConnect have the ability for IP white/black listing? I can't see it anywhere. Does Datapower have this core function and do I therefore have to implement my own policy to get to it?

Answer (score 1):

IBM API Connect does not have this policy out of the box.

Depending on your requirements you could either create an API Connect custom policy, that you use in your APIs assemble (if you need to white/black list on an API level) or what we did, that is to create Access control lists in Datapower appliance to restrict access (affecting all the APIs).

This is IBM documentation about Access control lists:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/acl.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that - I had thought this was the only option but I couldn't quite believe it :-) I'm comparing a number of API-M at the moment and most of them have this as standard policy. Ah well !